# How do I query in cakephp, if the date in the field 'created' of model 'listings' is more than 2 weeks ago?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a model 'listing' with a field 'created' which is in a datetime format.
I need to list in a view all listings that were created over 2 weeks ago.
An extra thing if possible is to somehow mark them as expired.

This is in cakePhp 1.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you can use a simple script to do that in cake.

```
      function meScript(){
            // first load your model if necessary
            $listingModel = ClassRegistry::init('Listing');

            // Then set your date margin to , two weeks back
            $date_margin =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-2 week')) ;

            // now retrieve all records that were created over 2 weeks ago  
            $listings = $listingModel ->find('all', array(
                                                        'conditions' => array('created <' => $date_margin),
                                                        )


                            );

}
```

That's pretty much it. Since the margin date is in "Y-m-d H:i:s" format, the " 'created <' => $date_margin" condition will retrieve all records that were created before that date.

As for the next step of marking them as expired:
Simply loop through the results and use their ids to set your 'expired' field (or whatever it is called in your database table) to 'true'.

Comment: Is this script to be put in the listings_controller like all other actions which I call from the view pages?? or in a separate JavaScript file?  My model 'listing' already has data in it and a controller  with CRUD actions I was just trying to show in a view page all listings that were over 2 weeks old.
I have just started learning cakephp.

Comment: This is written using php. So it definitely shouldn't go in a JavaScript file. yes, this one goes in your controller. you can use debug($listings); at the end of the above function to see if the results have been retrieved properly. 

I can see that you are new to cake. Better read up about model, retrieving & saving data at http://book.cakephp.org/view/66/Models. It will help you with the rest.

Comment: You could also put this code in the model layer (eg. `Listing::findExpired()`). This would allow you to call `$this->Listing->findExpired();` at controller level.
(You would need to put `return $listings;` at the bottom though.)

Comment: i also have problem to retrive data depends on date. In my table i store current timestamp when user is add with time() function. Now i want the count of user added on each day. so how can i write query